# Removing addresses / points within certain distance of each other and have the most points remaining?

Tags: qgis

I have a data set of nearly 2000 points. I would like to find out which points remain and the most possible if no points can be within x kilometers of another point. So, if one point was randomly chosen, then the next closest to be chosen would need to 1) be greater than x km away and 2) the next closest.

I would like to have the optimal result but it could also be good to be able to have the first point chosen at random and run that a few times to get an average result.